# F# Compiling VS Intellisense in .fs VS .fsx files

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

Visual Studio 2015, same F# 4.0 Console application.
Two files, a `Program.fs` file and a `Script.fsx` script file with the same code:

```
open FSharp.Core
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections

let seq = seq { 1 .. 3 }
let seqItem1 = Seq.nth(0) seq
let seqItem2 = Seq.item(0) seq
```

- `Program.fs` will not compile: ".item" constructor method not defined. No further messages from intellisense.
- `Script.fsx` works fine but Intellisense prompts that `Seq.nth` is deprecated, use `Seq.item` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this was due to the fact that I created the Project originally on VS 2015, but then for a while I had to work on VS2017. When switching to 2017, `FSharp.Core` could not be found between the project references for some reason -- I then added another reference to it, however I (wrongly) kept the old reference to the dll.

Switching back to VS2015 brought back the old `FSharp.Core` reference together with the other one added in VS2107. This resulted in the behavior stated in the question.

I still have to test whether bringing back the project to VS2017 will result in the `FSharp.Core` reference to not found again and the reason behind that.